# Refresh Yahoo OAuth 1.0 Access Token Using Passport

Tags: node.js, oauth, request, passport.js, yahoo

I have an Express app where I'm trying to refresh the Yahoo OAuth 1.0 access token before it expires after an hour so the user  doesn't have to re-login. I'm using the https-passport-yahoo-oauth Passport strategy, which works for the initial OAuth.

There's a strategy (passport-oauth2-refresh) for refreshing the OAuth 2.0 token here, which I haven't been able to get to work (obvious reasons, I suppose).

Yahoo docs on refreshing the access token here => https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-refreshaccesstoken.html

This is my code for initial OAuth is below. How can I then exchange the expire or expiring token for a new one based off this?

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});


 var strategy = new YahooStrategy({
    consumerKey: APP_KEY,
    consumerSecret: APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: (process.env.APP_URL || require('./conf.js').APP_URL) + 'auth/yahoo/callback'
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    var data = profile._json;

    var userObj = {
      id: profile.id,
      name: data.profile.nickname,
      avatar: data.profile.image.imageUrl,
      dateJoined: new Date().getTime(),
      lastUpdated: new Date().getTime(),
      lastVisit: new Date().getTime(),
      accessToken: token,
      tokenSecret: tokenSecret,
      sessionHandle: profile.oauth_session_handle
    };
    return done(null, userObj);
  }
);

passport.use(strategy);
```

I was thinking that I might be able to use Request, and roll my own token refresh, though I'm a little unsure with where to start there. Any help? Really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can totally do that using [request](https://github.com/request/request):

```
request.post('https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token', {
  oauth: {
    consumer_key:'...',
    consumer_secret:'...',
    token:'...',
    token_secret:'...',
    session_handle:'...'
  }
}, function (err, res, body) {})
```

Alternatively you can use [Purest](https://github.com/simov/purest#consumer-requests-to-update-access-token---oauth10) as well. Note that you should store the `session_handle` when the user authorizes your app for the first time.

Comment: Thanks! That totally worked. I stuck this at the end of a function I'm calling ever 30-minutes, and it looks like it's updating the token accordingly.